# Redirecionar através do valor de option e manter a mesma selecionada

Tags: javascript, html, select, redirect, option

Preciso redirecionar de acordo com o valor da "option" e manter essa "option" selecionada após o redirecionamento.

Já consigo redirecionar através deste código:

```
$(function() {
// bind change event to select
$('#categoria').on('change', function() {
var url = "https://" + window.location.hostname + "/search?q=" + $(this).val();    // get selected value
if (url) { // require a URL
  window.location.href = url; // redirect
}
return false;
});
});
```

Porém, quando redirecionado, a opção selecionada continua a primeira da lista.
Gostaria que, após o redirecionamento fica-se selecionada a opção escolhida.

Acredito que poderia fazer isso solicitando que fosse acrescentado a opção "select" a option de acordo com o valor após o parametro "=" na URL, porém não tenho conhecimento de como fazer isso.

Obs: só tenho acesso á HTML e Javascript, não possuo PHP (blogger host).

Edit 1: Digamos que a URL seja http://www.dominio.com/search?q=exemplo
e dentro do meu codigo eu tenha o seguinte:

```
<select>
<option value="exemplo">exemplo</option>
<option value="exemplo2">exemplo</option>
```

Sendo assim, devido o parametro da Url ser "exemplo" acrescente o "selected" na option, assim:

```
<select>
<option value="exemplo" selected>exemplo</option>
<option value="exemplo2">exemplo</option>
```

Comment: Se vc está redirecionando, vai sair da página, não?

Comment: Então sua pergunta não está explicando o que vc realmente quer. Se vc sair da página, não vai ver mais o select.

Comment: Sim, procuro se exista um script capaz de através de um parametro adicionar uma opção no option.
Ex: Se a url for: dominio.com/search?q=exemplo
e tiver uma option com value exemplo ela acrescente "selected" no codigo.

Comment: Acrescentei um "edit1" na pergunta, acho que não consegui explicar direito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode capturar o valor da variável `?q=` da URL atual e selecionar o `option` com o mesmo valor:

```
var url_ = new URL(location.href);
var variavel = url_.searchParams.get("q");
$("#categoria").val(variavel); // #categoria é o ID do select
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado.